Full Doxygen Documentation in vscode by hovering the mouse
I want to create doxygen documentation of my thesis. I want to add references in the functions descriptions eg:
  /*!
   * Sets the @ref state_ids variable. It requires that the bodies are passed
   * in the correct order in the `olympus_param.yaml`
   */
  void set_state_ids();

which generates a working link in the html page, as seen in the figure below.

However, when i see the documentation by having my cursor in the function in vscode, the text stops at the reference:

How can i fix this? so that the text that is shown when hovering the function is the full function description, so that it is usable inside the editor. And is it a vscode specific problem or it stems from using wrong keywords in the documentation.

Looks like a bug in VSCode or C++ extension.
